# Launcher icon not appearing in Action Bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar-compat, android-launcher

My launcher icon is not appearing in my ActionBar, despite having the `android:icon` attribute set (and the launcher appearing on my homescreen when I install the app). Note: I am using fragments, and they also contribute action items--but that shouldn't affect the home icon set, correct?

Here is some relevant code from my **manifest**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.mywebsite.myapp">

    <application
        android:name=".MyApp"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name">

        ...etc...

        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

And the code from **styles.xml**:

```
<resources>
    <style name="AppTheme" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <!-- Customize your theme here. -->
    </style>
</resources>
```

The code from **menu_main.xml**, for good measure:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<menu xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <!-- Note: my fragments also contribute action items. -->

    <item
        android:id="@+id/action_about"
        android:orderInCategory="100"
        android:title="@string/menu_item_about"
        app:showAsAction="never" />
</menu>
```

And some code from **MainActivity.java**:

```
package com.mywebsite.myapp;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
...etc...

public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

...lots of code; let me know if you need anything...

    // possibly relevant
    @Override public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMeunInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
    }
}
```

**EDIT:** This question is not a duplicate of the question linked to by the moderators. The answer to that question did not solve my problem; the answer I marked as correct below, however, did. To be specific, calling `setLogo(int)` was not the solution to my problem. Calling `actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);`, however, *did* solve my problem. See? Different questions.

Comment: Which API level? Using `AppCompat`? Using `Toolbar`?

Comment: I would like to see your `onCreate()` if it does anything regarding theming or display options.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you are displaying it:

```
actionBar.setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);
```

Then, note that `setIcon()` and `setLogo()` will only work if you have set `displayOptions` accordingly. You can just use:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_USE_LOGO);
```

So your `ActionBar` will take your `AndroidManifest.xml`'s icon. Or:

```
actionBar.setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_HOME | ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_TITLE);
actionBar.setIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `getActivity().getActionBar().setDisplayShowHomeEnabled(true);` in the fragment's `onCreate`